# Can we change to Alexa's own context and back from custom skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

When I say Alexa, tell me a joke, it will do so.

But say I am in between of a custom skill interaction, and I say Alexa tell me a joke, it will not give me a response as it is not handled in my custom skill.

I would like Alexa to handle responses like this automatically with a built-in response. Is there a way I can achieve this, get a joke (Alexa's own built-in response) and get back in my custom skill?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  For custom skills, Alexa requires that you do one of two things:

1. First use a command to activate it like "Use akshay's joke skill".  This might allow your skill to get triggered for subsequent Alexa commands, but not necessarily.  "Alexa, Tell me a joke" will most certainly be handled by Alexa's built-in functionality.
2. Specify the custom skill as part of the command.  "Ask akshay's joke skill to tell me a joke."

Option 2 is probably the closest you can come.